# Stuck at Thermodynamics problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, pressure

So I was trying to solve this problem:

> "What is the pressure generated in the tramcar pneumatic pump tank,
>   after blowing air 250 times, if the tank capacity is 30 liters and the
>   pump takes 600 cm3 of normal pressure air? Ignore the Temperature
>   variation."

My solution attempt:

> T=const. p1 = 10^5 Pa V1 = 600cm3 * 250 /1000000 = 0.15 m3 V2 = 30 l =
>   0.03 m3
>
> V1 * p1 = V2 * p2
>
> p2 = V1 * p1 / V2 = 0.15 m3 * 10^5 Pa / 0.03 m3 = 5 * 10^5 Pa

Yet the answer sheet says it's 6.1 * 10^5 Pa

So where I messed up ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the following: there is $30 + 0,6 \cdot 250$ L air, at first with a pressure of $101325$ Pa. Then it gets compressed to $30$ L, with no temperature change (or at least ignoring it).
What you did not take in account is that there is air in the tank at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I think the formula should be p1V1^(gamma)=p2V2^(gamma), where gamma = Cp/Cv, the ratio of the heat capacities at constant pressure and at constant volume.

Comment: Is it adiabatic how did you conclude

Comment: Use MathJax to format your equations.